# Asus X93S no fan sensor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fan, fancontrol

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus X93S.

So my problem is my installation not detected any fans with commandes : `sensors`

I got this result :

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:       +6280.4°C  

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.39 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:         N/A  (min =  +0.83 V, max =  +1.00 V)
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:        +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:        +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

So i try different things for try to fix this problem.

First i have try auto detect from `sudo sensors-detect --auto`

And this not fix.

Second i'll try this : `sudo pwmconfig`

And i got same result.

I think i have a mistake, because i can hear my fan who running, but sometimes i had my CPU temp go to 80° and fan is at the same speed ...

Thanks for you assistance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Good chance that the fan/s do not have sensors, only control by bios/temperature readings, so no OS will read them.  Only one of my laptops have fan sensors.

Comment: If we believe the first sensor, then your computer is a pile of molten lag and fan sensors won't help.

Comment: Rip, ok thanks for you're answer so i should go in bios settings ?

Comment: Bios probably won't tell much, fans usually just a hidden feature.  Will not hurt to look around, but unlikely to see.  I am just giving general info since I don't know Asus.  If you change/make new question title to mention Asus X93S no fan sensor, might get someone better, but think you only have three wire fan/s.  Need four wire fans to have sensors you can read.

Comment: Okay thanks for you're help i appreciate it